# Утечка памяти TStringList

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, память, delphi-xe5

Решил создать простую программку для проверки папки в режиме реального времени, ну, или почти. Создал форму, написал поток (Thread), в общем коде написал функцию реализующую почти весь необходимый мне функционал. Поток ещё не запускал, завязал запуск функции по щелчку на кнопке. В диспетчере задач увидел что почти через каждый щелчок увеличивается выделяемая память, хотя всё чищу.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чём проблема?

Код:

```
{ Функция чтения данных из установленной папки }
function TfrmMain.readDir(dir: string): string;
var
  listDirFile, listDataFile: TStringList;
  find: TSearchRec;
  loc_error: string;
  i, j, flag, listDirFileCount: Integer;
begin
  loc_error := '-1';
  listDirFile := TStringList.Create;
  listDataFile := TStringList.Create;

if FindFirst(dir + '\*', faArchive, find) = 0 then
begin
  repeat
    listDirFile.Add(find.Name);
  until FindNext(find) <> 0;
end;
listDirFileCount := listDirFile.Count;

if (listDirFileCount > 0) and (FileExists(DateToStr(Date))) then
begin
  listDataFile.LoadFromFile(DateToStr(Date));
end;

  for i := 0 to listDirFile.Count-1 do //Идём по listDirFile
  begin

    for j := 0 to listDataFile.Count-1 do //Идём по listDataFile
    begin
      if listDirFile[i] = listDataFile[j] then // Найдя 1 совпадение выходим
      begin
        flag := 1;
        Break;
      end;
    end;

    if flag = 1 then // Найдя первое совпадение и выйдя из предыдущего цикла, выходим
    begin
      listDirFile.SaveToFile(DateToStr(Date));
      Break;
    end;

  end;
listDataFile.LoadFromFile(DateToStr(Date));
drawTree(listDataFile);

listDataFile.Free;
listDirFile.Free;

Result := loc_error;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не хватает `FindClose(find)` после завершения поиска.
В справке на `FindFirst` черным по белому написано:

> FindFirst allocates resources (memory)
> that must be released by calling
> FindClose.

А вообще, для поиска утечек обычно используют [FastMM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) или еще какой инструмент, а не диспетчер задач.

Comment: Да, вы правы, моё упущение. Большое спасибо за ответ, он мне очень помог!

Comment: Если без сторонних компонент - можно воспользоваться опцией ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True для определения утечки. [источник](http://mirsovetov.net/show-memory-leek.html)